# Make a certain trapezoidal shape in pure css

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Suppose I have two div's, as (beautifully) displayed below. I have already taken a look [The Shapes of CSS](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/), but I haven't found out how exactly the yellow shape in below picture could be made. Is it possible to make the yellow shape in a similar manner to the things described in the link above.

[image: trapezoidal shape]

Or even, now we're on the subject, the picture below would describe the ideal situation. Is this possible in css, or using some other tools? (Note that the curves in the picture aren't ideal, but maybe a standard bezier curve with varying height would work?)

[image: Final]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second part of the question you can create SVG clip paths then reference the id in the css. You can see the SVGs at the bottom of the HTML.

```
-webkit-clip-path: url(#top-path);
clip-path: url(#top-path);
```

There are more details about both methods here: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

But be aware support for `clip-path` is quite limited at the moment.

http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

```css
div {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 130px;
}
.holder {
  position: relative;
}
.top {
  width: 490px;
}
.bottom {
  width: 490px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 35px;
}
.top-left {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  height: 35px;
}
.top-mid {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  width: 97px;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#top-path);
  clip-path: url(#top-path);
}
.top-right {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  margin-top: 37px;
  height: 53px;
}
.bottom-left {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 34px;
}
.bottom-mid {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 97px;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#bottom-path);
  clip-path: url(#bottom-path);
}
.bottom-right {
  background-color: aqua;
  margin-top: 55px;
  height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>SVG Clip Path Shape</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="top">
      <div class="top-left"></div>
      <div class="top-mid"></div>
      <div class="top-right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div class="bottom-left"></div>
      <div class="bottom-mid"></div>
      <div class="bottom-right"></div>
    </div>

    <svg width="0" height="0">
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="bottom-path">
          <path d="M14.966,0.68L0,0v33.113l14.966,0.68c29.252,2.041,55.102,70.509,76.068,70.503l6.245-0.32V54.864
 l-6.245,0.32C70.068,55.189,44.218,2.721,14.966,0.68z" />
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
    </svg>

    <svg width="0" height="0">
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="top-path">
          <path fill="#E30613" d="M88.763,36.612C59.511,33.053,45.639,0,13.327,0C9.346,0,0,0,0,0v33.113v1.622l14.966,0.68
 c29.252,2.041,55.102,54.509,76.068,54.503l6.245-0.32V69.847V36.735L88.763,36.612z" />
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
    </svg>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

For part one of the question we can use `clip-path` each of the corner coordinates is separated by a comma.

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 20%, 100% 100%, 0 43%);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 20%, 100% 100%, 0 43%);
```

```css
div {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 130px;
}
.holder {
  position: relative;
}
.top {
  width: 490px;
}
.bottom {
  width: 490px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 43px;
}
.top-left {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  height: 43px;
}
.top-mid {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 20%, 100% 100%, 0 43%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 20%, 100% 100%, 0 43%);
}
.top-right {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 80px;
}
.bottom-left {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 43px;
}
.bottom-mid {
  background-color: aqua;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 43%, 100% 100%, 0 43%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 43%, 100% 100%, 0 43%);
}
.bottom-right {
  background-color: aqua;
  margin-top: 43px;
  height: 57px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CSS Shape</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="top">
      <div class="top-left"></div>
      <div class="top-mid"></div>
      <div class="top-right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div class="bottom-left"></div>
      <div class="bottom-mid"></div>
      <div class="bottom-right"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Working on part two now, I may need a different strategy.

Answer (score 3):

Here is first shape in pure css. You need to use `perspective`.

```css
.shape {
  display: flex;
  margin: 50px;
}
.red,
.green {
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.green {
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 200px;
  height: 127px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  margin-left: -22px;
}
.red {
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  height: 56px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.parent {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 711px;
  perspective: 711px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  margin-top: 19px;
}
.el {
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-27deg) rotateY(-40deg);
  transform: rotateX(-27deg) rotateY(-40deg);
  height: 65px;
  background: #FFF200;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 350px;
  -webkit-perspective: 350px;
}
.el:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 200px 70px 0;
  border-color: transparent #FFF200 transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
  <div class="red">Div 1</div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="el"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="green">Div 2</div>
</div>
```